# Prevent systemd-boot menu from showing up every time lid is closed and hibernates with windows 10

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, systemd-boot

I have an laptop with two disks, and i am dual booting Arch Linux and Windows 10. Every time i close the lid of the PC and it hibernates the boot menu shows up. How can i prevent this, and make it so that the last used system/or active system is automatically selected? I use UEFI.

Comment: Welcome to U/L, and good question. However, I'm fairly sure that you can't. From the Linux perspective, when you hibernate, it stores the system state in swap. Windows cannot read swap, so can't know whether there is a hibernating Linux system or not. I presume this is also the case for Linux detecting a hibernating Windows system. Hence, the boot loader can't make a judgement over what is currently hibernating. Also, you can also have *both* systems hibernating at the same time, so it's unclear what the boot loader should do in that situation.